# Is possible to use sql language with a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, sql, pandas

i have a pandas dataframe named df containing 3 columns (col1, col2, col3).
How can i use sql this SQL query using python?

```
create table
select *,  sum(col1, -col3) as col4
from db
```

Also how can i do it in native python language(using pandas)?

Comment: 1) what is `col1-col3` ? 2) why grouping by `group by 1` ?

Comment: What do you mean with "col1-col3"? and what is "1", Is it "col1"? In the query your table is called "db" and in your explanation you said "df"

Answer (score 0):

you need to create a connection object using your DB credentials.
then you can use `read_sql` from pandas.
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html

Comment: but my db is in my local space, i create it just by importing it from excel, how could i connect with it?

Comment: im not familiar with this `importing it from excel`. normally DB has 4 credentials.
hostname, username, password and db_name. since its running locally hostname will be localhost.

see you can find the other credentials.

also you can just load it directly from excel there is a `read_excel` function in pandas

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to sum up col1-col3 (meaning col1, col2, col3)?

If I get your description correctly and you already have a dataframe called "df" then this should be fine:

```
df['col4'] = df.sum(axis=1)
```

EDIT:

pandas has a built in function called "read_sql" as the post below also states. But for this to work you first need to create an engine for example with "sqlalchemy" built-in function "create_engine" https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/engines.html

Here is a sample code that works for me:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine('mssql+pyodbc://%s/%s?driver=SQL+Server+Native+Client+11.0?charset=utf8' % ('YOURSERVERNAME','YOURDATABSENAME'))

df = pd.read_sql('SELECT  * FROM MYTABLE',engine)
```

I am not sure which SQL Driver you are using and maybe you need to change this.

YOURSERVER is called '(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB' in my case.

Comment: i'm sorry it doesn't answer my quest: how would you do it using sql (connecting with pandas dataframe and make the query)

Comment: in your description it says "i have a pandas dataframe named df"

Comment: in my description is also written this: How can i use sql to this SQL query using python?

Comment: @lucapellerossapelles see my edit for an option. Other option could be to load the excel file directly with pandas and then do the calculation with the dataframe like I posted before.